# Axios post request error: 422 Unprocessable Entity

Tags: python, reactjs, axios, fastapi

I've been trying to build this stock prediction web app using Prophet model and FastAPI. I'm stuck at this problem where I'm getting console log error: 422 Unprocessable Entity.

Here's the react code to get API request:

```
async function GetAPI () {

    const [predData, setPred] = React.useState();
    const [stock_name, setStock] = React.useState();
    
    const axios = require('axios');
    
    var data = JSON.stringify({
      "ticker": stock_name
    })
    
    try{
      let response = await axios({
        method: 'post',
        url:'http://0.0.0.0:8000/predict',
        headers: {
          'accept' : 'application/json',
          'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
        },
        data: data
      },
      )
      if (response.status==200){
        console.log(response.data);
        setPred(response.data);
      }
      return {predData}
    
    }
    catch(error){
      console.log(error);
    
    }

}
```

This is the FastAPI function in my python backend:

```
@app.post("/predict") 
def prediction(payload: StockIn):
    stock_name = payload.stock_name
    pred = stock_prediction(stock_name)
    a = int(pred)
    response_object = {"data" : a }
    return response_object
```

Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: Are you supposed to stringify before the post?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you send {'ticker': '...'}.
And in backend you try to access a property called `stock_name`.
Most likely this is caused by it.

If that doesn't help, check below.

It seems that your situation is related with your backend, so you can edit the header.

You can check the variables by simply adding
print statements after important parts.
For example;

```
@app.post("/predict") 
def prediction(payload: StockIn):
    print('Payload:', payload)
    stock_name = payload.stock_name     
    pred = stock_prediction(stock_name)
    print('Pred:', pred)
    a = int(pred)     
    response_object = {"data" : a }    
    return response_object
```

**NOTE:** It's about backend because axios doesn't interfere with the response codes.

Comment: stock_name is a var passed from a different component, this code worked when I tried to test API using FastAPI interface. It's just I can't make my react code pass a stock name and get an output out of it.

Comment: You don't seem to pass a stock_name from a component, you are sending your data as {'ticker': '...'} and in the server side you can access it by payload.get('ticker') I suppose. Can you try it? And also, as @ConorReid said, "Are you supposed to stringify before the post?"